# Faster method for Nonmetric Multidimensional Scaling of large data

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a dissimilarity vector `D` of size 1x460320 made with `pdist` function. I want to calculate a Nonmetric Multidimensional Scaling (NMDS) for it, but it takes very long time (about 30 min on a fast computer, for one replicate, which is not so reliable. I usually take 10 replicates).

The code I'm using for this is:

```
[Y,stress,disparities] = mdscale(D,2,'criterion','stress','start','random','replicates',1);
```

I know that this is large data, and that's why it takes so long, but I wonder if there is any way to make it work faster? are there any more efficient functions or methods for that?

Comment: According to [this tutorial](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/mvahtmlnode100.html) it seems that, similar to k-means algorithm , the main computational bottleneck is distance calculations.[Here](https://avira.github.io/dsblog/2016-09-01-speeding-up-k-means.html) you can see some methods for speeding up the k-means algorithm. I believe the same ideas can be used to speed up Multidimensional Scaling algorithm.

Comment: @rahnema1 thanks! I'll look into that.